# Null Pointer Exception for prepared statement Sql Connection in java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have gone to same type of questions in this forum, but their solutions are not helping here. I am trying to run following code in java while trying to connect to MySql workbench:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement st =null;
    try
    {   
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    con  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root","password"); 
    String sql = "select * from city where id = 1";
    st = con.prepareStatement(sql);            <---- here the error is shown
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int id = rs.getInt("ID");
        String Name = rs.getString("Name");
        String CountryCode = rs.getString("CountryCode");
        String District = rs.getString("District");
        int Population = rs.getInt("Population");
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(Name);
        System.out.println(CountryCode);
        System.out.println(District);
        System.out.println(Population);         
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();    
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();        
}finally
{
    try{
         if(st!=null)
            st.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(con!=null)
            con.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

I am getting the following error majorly:

```
 --> PreparedStatement.java:4063 com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.toString()
  --> PreparedStatement.java:587 com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql()
   --> PreparedStatement.java:591 
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(false)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(PreparedStatement.java:649)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(PreparedStatement.java:587)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.toString(PreparedStatement.java:4068)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printParameters(Tracer.aj:240)
at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printEntering(Tracer.aj:167)
at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.entry(Tracer.aj:126)
at    com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.ajc$before$com_mysql_jdbc_trace_Tracer$1$f51c62b8(Tracer.aj:45)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.registerStatement(Connection.java)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.<init>(Statement.java:270)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:500)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.clientPrepareStatement(Connection.java:2187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4829)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4734)
at Filereader.DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:19)

 --> Connection.java:2199 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.close()
--> Connection.java:4892 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.realClose(true, true, false, null)
--> Connection.java:4343 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isClosed()
```

What is wrong here in the code? As per my knowledge, prepared statement for DB Connectivity is written correct and Sql query format is also seems fine.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the JDBC driver, there's no way you should be getting an exception from in there. What version of the driver JAR are you using? Is there a more recent version?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin-g.jar

Comment: It looks like you're using an AspectJ-based Tracer which logs the statements executed by the JDBC driver, and which causes this bug of the driver to happen.

Comment: yes I have aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar in my library. Should I use some other version or some other JDBC jar file?

Comment: I have tested your code with mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar. Your code works fine. I would suggest you to replace your mysql jar with mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar

Comment: One more point - **don't** use root user for querying, and especially on the web. That is: create separate user with limited rights for that