# Insert multiple Records retrieved from JSON which is parsed using POJO in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc

I am trying to insert JSON data retrieved from Rest API which is parsed by Jackson using POJO.
I am getting null pointer exception while inserting the records based on the below line of code at **preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);**

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here??

```
 Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO Test_Batch"
            + "((Account_ID, BestPractice_Source, Check_ID, Importance,Category,Last_BestPractices_Checked_Date,Last_BestPractices_Updated_Date))                                                                          VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
         JsonNode root =mapper.readTree(new RestClient().Json());
          ArrayNode BestPracticeChecks=(ArrayNode)root.path("BestPracticeChecks");
              Iterator<JsonNode> iterator =BestPracticeChecks.elements();   
              BestPracticeChecks bestPracticeChecksid =null;    
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {                                 
                      bestPracticeChecksid = mapper.readValue(iterator.next().traverse(), BestPracticeChecks.class);                      
                          preparedStatement.setInt(1, Account_ID);
                          preparedStatement.setString(2, "xyz");
                          preparedStatement.setInt(3, bestPracticeChecksid.getCheckId());
                          preparedStatement.setString(4, bestPracticeChecksid.getImportance());
                          preparedStatement.setString(5, bestPracticeChecksid.getCategory());
                          preparedStatement.setTimestamp(6, getCurrentTimeStamp());
                          preparedStatement.setString(7, readDateofResults());
                          preparedStatement.addBatch();

        }

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();

        dbConnection.commit();
```

The error log as below:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(PreparedStatement.java:586)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(PreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.toString(PreparedStatement.java:3551)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printParameters(Tracer.aj:240)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printEntering(Tracer.aj:167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.entry(Tracer.aj:126)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.ajc$before$com_mysql_jdbc_trace_Tracer$1$f51c62b8(Tracer.aj:45)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.registerStatement(Connection.java)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.<init>(Statement.java:197)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:442)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.asSql(ServerPreparedStatement.java:347)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.asSql(PreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.toString(ServerPreparedStatement.java:2327)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printParameters(Tracer.aj:240)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.printEntering(Tracer.aj:167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.entry(Tracer.aj:126)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.trace.Tracer.ajc$before$com_mysql_jdbc_trace_Tracer$1$f51c62b8(Tracer.aj:45)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.registerStatement(Connection.java)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.<init>(Statement.java:197)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.<init>(ServerPreparedStatement.java:280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4363)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4301)
    at com.tutorialspoint.JDBCBatchUpdateExample.batchInsertRecordsIntoTable(JDBCBatchUpdateExample.java:49)
    at com.tutorialspoint.JDBCBatchUpdateExample.main(JDBCBatchUpdateExample.java:29)
```

Comment: `conn` is `null`? You need to initialize the connection object. Also, never swallow exceptions and make sure you at least log them. This will make troubleshooting problems like these much easier.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, its just a code snippet, before the code shown above I have initialize the conn by
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

Comment: Is there any other way I can insert JSON values (mapped with Pojo) in database using JDBC?

Comment: You must be getting an error message of some sort in the log file. Please share it.

Comment: I have changed my code and attached the error log aswell, still I am facing the same issue of Null Pointer Exception. @MickMnemonic

Comment: Thanks @MickMnemonic, I got the issue resolved..!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above issue by upgrading the mysql connector jar to latest available. Seems like the tracer.aj was masking the process and hence was showing the null pointer exception. I never doubted my code for once :) 
Credit : [Null Pointer Exception for prepared statement Sql Connection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327841/null-pointer-exception-for-prepared-statement-sql-connection-in-java)